# PVC conduit termination with a junction box

Tags: conduit

I’m running two 3/4” conduits coming in from the front yard into the house. I suppose I could use two lb conduit bodies for each conduit run but could I use an empty junction box (say 4x4x2) instead? Would be a bit tidier than 2 conduit bodies next to each other attached to  the siding.

Comment: This is indoors, right? If the junction box is outdoors you'd likely have to go with a weatherproof box.

Comment: Outdoors… so yes definitely weatherproof. Home Depot have a few Carlon ones, I need to drill holes for the conduit adapters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, that's fine.

As far as fill, when a junction box has nothing but passthru wires in it (so it's acting like a conduit body), then its fill rules work the same as a conduit body (not likely to have a problem).